# Second small surface one integrated CPU

Tags: computer-engineering, computer-hardware, microelectronics

I was changing the thermal paste of my CPU and I noticed, there where two metallic surfaces but only one was covered with thermal paste. The heatsink-plate is big enough to cover both surfaces, though. However, this was factory-set and during my research I found a tutorial-video where they covered only one surface.

For better comprehensibility: It is an i5-8259U CPU, built into my Thinkpad E490. I also attached a photo of the cleaned up CPU.
So I have two questions, and I couldn't find much during my research for them:

1. What is this second, smaller component on the CPU and why is it not cooled? I thought, it might be the integrated graphics chip - but that's rather more a guess. Also, why wouldn't a graphics chip be cooled?
2. Is there any reason it would be harmful to just apply thermal paste to the second surface too? As far as I know, none of these microelectronic components need a temperature higher than room-temperature to run properly.

If you are asking yourself, why i would change somethink in the first place: Whenever i use aplications, which would benefit from a propper gpu, the cpu is thermal-throttling almost continuously. So i thought it might be worth a try.

Thank you for your help.

[image: i5-8259U]

Comment: Are those two surfaces at the same height from the bottom line? I don't think an off center load on the heat sink is a great idea to keep the assy planarity and hence thermal conductivity

Comment: Yes they are the same height. And when reinstalling the heatsink, it felt like it was sitting on both surfaces.

Comment: I see, then It would probably make sense having thermal paste on both.

Comment: Allright, thank you. I think i will just try it and run a benchmark test to check if it made any differences.

Comment: This is not metal, this is silicon and it is fragile and thin, be careful.